# Meta Descriptions and JSON Schema for Category Pages

Tags: schema.org, meta-description, json-ld

We are a referral business - like Yelp, but in a different space.
We added JSON-LD for local businesses on our destination/category pages.
The addition of JSON-LD increased our ranks substantially.
Now we're seeing it decline because Google replaced the meta description with the description of some of the projects on the page - although for some reason they started in the middle of the page.

Any thoughts on how to get meta descriptions to show and get the ranking benefit at the same time?

Comment: We would need an example of your description meta-tag and search terms that are being used. As well, what search terms have been returning the projects pages incorrectly? This is your clue to craft a description meta-tag.